# How to create iteration scoped variables inside ForEach activities in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a `ForEach` activity where inside each iteration, I need to set a few iteration specific variables.  I can achieve this by using variables defined for the pipeline (pipeline scope), but this forces me to run the loop in `Sequential` mode so that multiple iterations running in parallel will not update the same variable.  What I really need is the ability to define these variables within each iteration (iteration scope) so that I can run the `ForEach` activity in parallel mode.

[image]

[image]

I've considered creating a SQL dataset where I could do a lookup for fake values (SELECT 1 AS var1, 2 AS var2) just to get a structure where I can set and use those values, but that seems really lame.  I've also considered using an array variable type with the AppendVariable option, but that introduces a lot of custom parsing.

Would be nice if I could just have an InMemory dataset that doesn't have to be tied to a data source where I could use it as a structure inside my ForEach iteration.  Does anyone have any other ideas about how to set iteration specific variables inside `ForEach` loop?

Comment: Wow, is this true. So in fact, you cannot really use *variables* inside ForEach loops that run in parallel? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I believe this is still true.  Variables are declared at the pipeline level at this time (think class level variables).

Comment: @MartinWickman It IS documented somewhere in MSDN - I recall coming across this a few days ago. It's not obvious though - it's buried a few paragraphs into a page, somewhere.

Comment: what is even more maddening is this will get through your debug runs just fine as those are executed in serial in adf...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the best way to currently do this it to pull the values from an outer lookup or get metadata activity if you can. using the inner lookup wouldn't be as cost efficient or performance efficient. especially if you were iterating over 100's or thousands. Of course this is if you can determine the values for each iteration ahead of time. if you can't than. I would drably go for your lookup approach. or if you can get away from the variables entirely just set the values using an expression using dynamic properties.

Comment: I don't know the value ahead of time which is why I have that switch inside the loop.  I could probably write some huge expression is that is the equivalent of the switch statement for each "variable", but I have feeling like that will be pretty ugly and difficult to maintain.  Using the switch to handle all the various ways that a variable can be set seemed easier to read so that the stored procedure is simply to understand by just referencing the variable.

Comment: If I create a fake lookup on a dataset, do I have the ability write values to it?  Like I would do a fake "SELECT NULL AS var1, NULL AS var2" and then write the real value to the dataset/var1 and dataset/var2 fields: output.firstRow.var1 = 'myData'

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the lookup can return what ever values you'd like.. including creating them based on expressions howrver that return value becomes unchangeable... without seeing the other branches of the switch and the switch expression it seems like it could work.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying so I don't think it will work.  Here is an expression that I do in one of the switch statements where I just take the first four characters of the file name to get a code "@substring(activity('GetFileMetadata').output.itemName, 0, 4)".   In another case it may be in the middle of the file name, and in another it may not be there at all (depends on the source of file...hence the switch).  So if a lookup can be done against the file, then each SetExpression could be replaced with a Lookup on the file maybe if I understand you correctly.

Comment: This seems more complicated than it needs to be so maybe I'm just not understanding something.  At the end of the day, all I need is a place to store calculated values based on a condition within a loop and then use them in a later activity.

Comment: I ended up just moving all this logic to a stored procedure and doing a lookup on it.  Thank for the help

Answer (score 6):

I agree, this is very annoying and irritating.

If the first part of Jason's answer is vaiable for your situation, then that's definitely the way to go. (Define the variables outside the loop).

But assuming that the variables are dynamically calculated per-iteration, then the only solution that I know is to define the body of the Foreach loop as its own pipeline. Now you can define variable inside that inner pipeline, which are "scoped" to the separate executions of the inner-pipeline.

Quite a lot of ADF's pipeline limitations can be circumvented like this. Nested Ifs/Foreaches, Activity limits, etc.

Comment: This is also the way I would also do it: define an inner pipeline and pass in the iteration-specific values to that execution.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround that worked for me was to use a Filter Activity. It's not super pretty but can help.

Say you want to assign `expr` to a variable. Just add a filter activity and configure it like this:

**Items:** `@array(expr)`

**Condition:** `@equals(1, 1)`

Then instead of using a variable simply use the Filter Activity output like this:

`@first(activity('<your filter activity name>').output.Value)`

Comment: This worked for me when I ran into this issue today.